# Registrar dado em celula de uma tabela excel vba

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho um userform para registrar um dado na tabela TabelaViagens. No formulario eu seleciono a viagem no combobox e para registrar o dado utilizo evento no botao aprovar. Contudo o codigo não está funcionando, sempre passando para o MsgBox. Chequei o valor que a matriz(i, 1) está recebendo, e sempre se refere ao valor do último registro da coluna 1. Por algum motivo o cb_viagem.Value passa esse valor.

Como corrigir?

Segue arquivo. Eu diminui a base de dados para facilitar os testes. Mas mesmo assim não consigo identificar o problema. [Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mrZLehHlFjysp1GAd8kyu51FeKsupvG_)

```
Private Sub Aprovar_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="gpq"

    If cb_viagem.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Selecione a Viagem!!"
    Else


        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Dim i As Long
        Dim matriz As Variant
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planejamento") 'ou para declarar com o nome da planilha: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")
        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TabelaViagens") 'No seu caso: .ListObjects("Atividades")
        With tbl
            matriz = .DataBodyRange              'Cria matriz

            For i = UBound(matriz) To LBound(matriz) Step -1
                If matriz(i, 1) = cb_viagem.Value And matriz(i, 28) = 0 Then

                    matriz(i, 28).Value = "1"
                    matriz(i, 29).Value = "Aprovado"

                    ' .ListRows(i).Delete

                    Exit For

                Else: MsgBox "Viagem já foi aprovada ou negada!"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Se puder criar um [mcve] com uma tabela com valores que gerem este erro. Pois o código parece estar correto.

Comment: Adicionei o arquivo. O mesmo problema está ocorrendo com o userform de exclusão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que você tem um problema dentro do seu `for` loop . Eu suponho que a ideia era iterar as linhas da matriz de baixo para cima, procurando o número da viagem correspondente.

Isto não ocorre pois o loop é terminado logo na primeira iteração visto que há instruções `Exit For` tanto nas condições `if` como `else`. Logo, caso `matriz(Ubound(matriz), 1)` (último registro da coluna 1) não seja igual a `cb_viagem.Value` (valor selecionado da viagem), a rotina se encerra com a mensagem que você está vendo.

A rotina `Aprovar_Click()` corrigida ficaria:

```
Private Sub Aprovar_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="gpq"
If cb_viagem.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Selecione a Viagem!!"
 Else


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim matriz As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planejamento")                         'ou para declarar com o nome da planilha: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TabelaViagens")   'No seu caso: .ListObjects("Atividades")
With tbl
    matriz = .DataBodyRange                   'Cria matriz

    For i = UBound(matriz) To LBound(matriz) Step -1
        If Trim(matriz(i, 1)) = cb_viagem.Value Then
          If Trim(matriz(i, 30)) = 0 Then

            With ws.ListObjects("TabelaViagens")
              .DataBodyRange(i, 30).Value = 1
              .DataBodyRange(i, 31).Value = "Aprovada"
            End With

          Else: MsgBox "Viagem já foi aprovada ou negada!"""
          End If
          Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

End If



ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="gpq"


End Sub
```

E a rotina `Delete_Click()` (que você comentou estar falhando) corrigida ficaria:

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="gpq"
If CB_Viagens.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Selecione a Viagem!!"
 Else


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim matriz As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planejamento")                         'ou para declarar com o nome da planilha: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agosto")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TabelaViagens")   'No seu caso: .ListObjects("Atividades")
With tbl
    matriz = .DataBodyRange                   'Cria matriz

    For i = UBound(matriz) To LBound(matriz) Step -1
        If Trim(matriz(i, 1)) = CB_Viagens.Value Then

          If matriz(i, 28) = NomeUsuario() Then

            .ListRows(i).Delete

          Else: MsgBox "Você não tem permissão para excluir essa viagem. Apenas quem criou o registro pode excluir!"
          End If

          Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

OBS: Note que tive de mudar alguns índices de coluna da variável `matriz` para condizer com o a planilha que você forneceu.

Comment: Obrigado. Ao executar a aprovação só insere os valores nas células 30 e 31 quando a combobox está com valor da ultima linha da tabelaViagens. Se seleciono outro valor, o botão não executa nenhuma açao, nem mesmo a MsgBox dispara. Mesmo caso da Exclusão, só exclui quandoselecionada a ultima linha.

Comment: Jarbas, parece que os números de viagem lidos eram retornados com um espaço, fazendo com que o teste falhasse. Fiz uma alteração adicionando a função `trim()`, veja se funciona agora.